# Qt5: How to create a (cleanup) task that runs once per day at 3:00am?

Tags: multithreading, qt, task, multitasking, resource-cleanup

I am using Qt5 under Windows7.
I know how to create a task using QThread, but my problem is:
How do I run it every day at 03:00AM?
I was thinking about QTimer, but it doesn't seem to be ok... it can't be linked somehow to 03:00am.

**Just to make it clear**: I can't use some Windows application(s). It must be coded inside my Qt app as it does some cleaning job too: cleanup history list, trim it down to 1000 lines (or whatever), etc. So, you see I can't do that using TaskScheduler or similar Windows tools...

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the application is actually running?

Comment: It is a kind of server (TCP comm), etc. So, it is supposed to be up'n running all day long...

Comment: Code snippet given above as example by Kuba Ober seems ok, BUT in order to get it compiled one MUST correct a typo: "sheduleCleanup()" change it with "scheduleCleanup()". I didnt test it but I see no reason why it would not work. Thanks K.O.!

Comment: @Kuba Ober : Well, I tried thr example from the link you provided but it seems the timeout signal doesnt fire up...?!?  I tested twice....Any idea why / what is happening? I'm using qDebug("Some message"); in the SLOT to check that, and I see/get nothing... ;(

Answer (score 1):

you can use windows task scheduler to do this for you

[image]

Comment: I agree. Much better to have the scheduler periodically start the application than have it sitting around waiting until 3am.

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I am looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with using a `QTimer`? I agree that a task scheduler is the better option. Here, only about `0,03%` of the time code is executed it is really supposed to do something. If the exact moment is not as important you can increase the timer interval and the check-boundaries and reduce the unncessary calls. But if you prefer such a solution this should work:

```
someclass::someclass(){

    member_timer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(member_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(check_time()));
    member_timer->start(30000);

    member_cleanup_performed = false;
}

void someclass::check_time(){

    QTimer ctime = QTime::currentTime();
    if(ctime.hour() == 3 && ctime.minute() == 0){

        if(member_cleanup_performed == false){
            this->cleanup();
            member_cleanup_performed = true;
        }
    }else{
        member_cleanup_performed = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: QTime class offers a method "int  secsTo(const QTime & t) const" that I think can be used to optimize the above code. At lest, I would do it this way :) It would be much elegant and also it would avoid pumping checking at each 30 secs. Just an idea :)

Comment: @groenhen Yes I saw this in the now-linked question. Definitely a better solution but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11, have a look at [std::this_thread::sleep_until](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until).
Run it in a separate thread and let the thread emit a signal connected to a slot in the main thread, which then performs the action. That of course requires that your application is actually running at 3 am.

Comment: That's a possibility, but wasting a thread, and thus about 1MB of virtual memory, just so that you can do nothing for a long time seems crazy.